# How to change canvas to square without using -extent (retaining the longest edge)

Tags: imagemagick

After batch trimming a folder of images, how to then make the canvas square, whilst retaining the longest edge? I don't want to use -extent and make them all a fixed width.

Examples of desired output:

- 800x1200 becomes 1200x1200
- 1000x600 becomes 1000x1000
- 1625x1600 becomes 1625x1625 etc....

So for example, if -squared was a function, it would be something like:

```
mogrify -path squared/ -trim -background white -gravity center  quality 75 -squared *.jpg
```

How to achieve this? I use ImageMagick v6.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed, it's totally relevant to programming and software tools (not the only tool around here it would seem though). Plenty of ImageMagick posts on this site.  Super weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on ImageMagick 7, you can do the following with -extent to get the max of w and h.

Input:

[image]

```
magick barn.jpg -background black -gravity center -extent "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]" x.png
```

[image]

In ImageMagick 6, you can do something similar by using the viewport computations with -distort SRT, but you have to add the offset computations, since -gravity does not work with -distort SRT.

```
convert barn.jpg -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]+%[fx:(w-max(w,h))/2]+%[fx:(h-max(w,h))/2]" -virtual-pixel black -filter point -distort SRT 0 +repage y.png
```

[image]